# "something we wanted to do but we didn't", is the second "we" optional?

Tags: ellipsis

Some guy is talking about the use of would have and the past
participle

> we use it to talk about
>   something we wanted to do but **didn't**

I would have said

> we use it to talk about
>   something we wanted to do but **we didn't**

Is the second "we" that functions as subject of the clause follows "but" required, optional or unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's optional as already in the beginning u stated the 'we'. It only becomes redundancy in the 2nd case to use it again.

Comment: So, it is better to omit the second "we", right?

Comment: Yeah, that's wt I feel .

Comment: This is a bad answer. It's so incomplete as to be misleading.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation and spelling.

Comment: @Lambie you'll probably have to edit it yourself. After almost 4 years of silence, I doubt Adi Reddy will read the comment or even care.